# Change of Address (Google Webmasters Tools) Error

Tags: domains, google-search-console, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

I have 301 permanently redirected my old domain `http://oldexample.asia` to my new domain `http://newexample.org` but my site is hosted in `Wapka.mobi` (free hosting service) which automatically redirects the domain to `http://newexample.org/index.xhtml`. 
I have added & verified `newexample.org` in Google Webmasters Tools but it says the redirected domain is not the same because of the `/index.xhtml`
I tried verifying `http://newexample.org/index.xhtml` but it redirects to already verified `http://newexample.org`
Is there any way to verify `http://newexample.org/index.xhtml` as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution,

Temporarily add both the domains in your own server and verify them again if asked. And then follow the verification process.
Here is the success image:

[image]