# Change of Address, Error in site redirection on Google Console

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, https

I am trying to change my domain on Google Search console using Change of Address tool, and for some reasons Google is throwing an error saying:

`The old site redirects to edbinx.com, which does not correspond to the new site you chose.`

Just to confirm that my 301 is working, I tried making cURL calls and got the expected 301 redirects, I don't know where I am going wrong with this on Google Console.

I found this question very similar to the issue I am facing, [Change of Address (Google Webmasters Tools) Error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/85132/change-of-address-google-webmasters-tools-error), but unfortunately I cannot implement the answer provided.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is edbinx not your new site?

Comment: Nope, the new website is error.how

Comment: How did you check your redirects?   If Google is seeing different redirects, either Google is wrong, your checks are wrong, or your site is hacked.    Google doesn't usually get those things wrong.

Comment: If I do a `cURL edbinx.com` on my terminal I get 301 redirect with the right location. Also, on the other online to check redirect I am getting right results apart from Google

Comment: So edbinx.com is your old site and Google thinks it is redirecting to itself?

Comment: Yep. We can believe that

Comment: OK, I found the problem and provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not redirecting HTTP (as opposed to HTTPS) and `www.` properly.   This redirect is correct:

```
$ curl https://edbinx.com --head
HTTP/2 301
location: https://error.how/
```

However, these three redirects are not correct.  They should all point directly at your new site, not redirect to the canonical form of your old site:

```
$ curl http://www.edbinx.com/ --head
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.edbinx.com/

$ curl http://edbinx.com/ --head
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://edbinx.com/

$ curl https://www.edbinx.com/ --head
HTTP/2 301 
location: https://edbinx.com/
```

If you change those three redirects to point directly to `https://error.how/` then Google will be able to process your change of address correctly.